# Playing DRM Mpeg-DASH video with VideoJS

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js

I'm currently building a website which will use VideoJS 5 to play DASH videos. While the player plays pure DASH videos fine I'm having problems with playing Widevine DRM encrypted Dash videos. The video source is defined as below;

```
player.src({"type": videoType, "src": urlOfVideoSource , "keySystemOptions": [{
    "name": "com.widevine.alpha",
    "options": {"licenseUrl": "https://proxy.uat.widevine.com/proxy"}
  }]});
```

The strange thing is that when I play this file: (https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/art-of-motion_drm/mpds/11331.mpd)  the player plays it just fine.
But when I try to play this (http://html5.cablelabs.com:8100/cenc/wv/dash.mpd) the player return me a 'POST 403 error. Both are DRM encrypted.

None of the CableLabs Test Content Widevine videos from Dashif website are working with my player currently.